# Auth->login() function not working properly

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.6

Here's the component declaration in **AppController.php**>

```
'Auth' => array(
    'authenticate' => array(
        'Form' => array(
            'userModel' => 'User',
            'fields' => array('username' => 'email', 'password' => 'code'),
            'scope' => array('activated' => true),
        ),
    ),
    'loginAction' => array('controller' => 'users', 'action' => 'login'),
    'loginRedirect' => array('controller' => 'members', 'action' => 'dashboard', 'admin' => true),
    'authError' => 'No Permission',
    'logoutRedirect' => array('controller' => 'pages', 'action' => 'home'),
    'userScope' => array('User.activated' => true),
),
```

The login form:

```
<?= $this->Form->create('User', array('url' => '/users/login', 'class' => 'form-inline'));?>
    <div class="form-group">
        <?= $this->Form->input('User.email', array(
            'div' => false,
            'label' => false,
            'placeholder' => 'е-пошта',
            'class' => 'form-control',
            'required' => true,
        ));?>
        <?= $this->Form->input('User.code', array(
            'div' => false,
            'label' => false,
            'placeholder' => 'сериски број',
            'class' => 'form-control',
            'required' => true,
        ));?>
        <?= $this->Form->button('<i class="fa fa-user"></i>', array('type' => 'submit', 'class' => 'btn btn-primary', 'escape' => false));?>
    </div>
<?= $this->Form->end();?>
```

And a snippet of the login function:

```
// ...
if($this->request->is('post')) {
    if($this->Auth->login()) {
        if(isset($this->request->data['User']['token']) && $this->request->data['User']['token']) {
            $token = substr(md5(time()), 0, 32);
            $this->User->id = $this->Auth->user('id');
            $this->User->saveField('token', $token);
            $this->Cookie->write('remember_me', $token, false, '1 week');
        }
        return $this->redirect($this->Auth->loginRedirect);
    }
    // ...
```

Now, when I use `$this->Auth->login($this->request->data)` or `$this->Auth->login($this->request->data['User'])`, it works, but when I use only `$this->Auth->login()` it doesn't. I can do a workaround by logging in with `$this->request->data` and then putting the rest of the user data manually to be available afterwards, but I want to know why this happens. Any ideas?

**EDIT**

So, as Karthik Keyan mentioned hashing, i figured this was the problem. CakePHP was automatically hashing the password (code field) and I didn't want it to. So I made a custom hasher class named NoPasswordHasher as follows:

```
App::uses('AbstractPasswordHasher', 'Controller/Component/Auth');

class NoPasswordHasher extends AbstractPasswordHasher {
    public function hash($password) {
        return $password;
    }

    public function check($password, $hashedPassword) {
        return $password == $hashedPassword;
    }
}
```

and used it in the Auth component:

```
'Auth' => array(
    'authenticate' => array(
        'Form' => array(
            'userModel' => 'User',
            'fields' => array('username' => 'email', 'password' => 'code'),
            'scope' => array('activated' => true),
            'passwordHasher' => 'No',
        ),
    ),
```

It works now. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Tell what type of errors can be display for you.Please check can you store the password in HASH (salt) format.

Comment: The password (code) is not hashed, it should be checked in the raw format.

Comment: Cakephp 2.6. You pointed out the problem, now I am looking for a way to disable the automatic hash of the Auth component.

Comment: I think cakephp can be support only salt password

Comment: I cannot disable the password hashing?

Comment: Could you please explain your problem, Sry not understand

Comment: I don't want my password hashed. It is stored as it is, and when I log in, I don't want anything hashed. I want the automatic hashing disabled. I tried setting `'passwordHasher' => false` in the component declaration, but it doesn't take false as an option.